# How to handle leap years in Ada

Tags: ada

I'm supposed to do a program that handles the dates of a year. I'm having a problem with handling the leap year in a good way. I'm not going to post the entire code because it'll be too much. My program runs but I don't like how my last if statement looks.

Information about months and leap years:

```
Month: Jan  Feb    Mar   Apr  May   Jun   Jul    Aug   Sep   Okt   Nov    Dec 
Days : 31   28/29  31     30   31    30    31     31    30    31   30     30
```

A year is a leap year if it's evenly dividable by 4, but not even when divided by 100. Years are also evenly dividable by 400 leap years. If it's a leap year, February has 29 days instead of 28.

This is my code (only the part I need help with):

```
      Get(Days);
    
      if Days > 31 or Day < 1 then 
        raise Day_Error;
    
      elsif Day = 31 and (Month = 2 or Month = 4 or Month = 6 or Month = 9 or Month = 11) then
        raise Day_Error;
    
      elsif Day = 30 and (Month = 1 or Month = 3 or Month = 5 or Month = 7 or 
                          Month = 8 or Month = 10 or Month = 12) then
        raise Day_Error;
      end if;
    
      if Day = 29 and Month = 2 then 
        if Year mod 400 = 0 or (Year mod 4 = 0 and Year mod 100 /= 0) then
          null; 
        else 
          raise Day_Error;
        end if;
      end if;

      exit;
    end; 
  end loop;    
end Day_Procedure;
```

My concern is the if statement where I put `Day = 29` and `Month = 2`, can this be solved without having the need to put two if statements?

Comment: Ada provides packages to handle date and time activities. The two packages you want to look for are Ada.Calendar and Ada.Calendar.Formatting. These packages automatically handle leap years.

Comment: I can't use these packages, I have to define then myself :/

Comment: You may want to introduce the functions `Is_Leap_Year (Year)` and `Days_In_Month (Year, Month)`.

Comment: Regarding the packages suggested by @JimRogers, you can read the sources for guidance and use them to unit test your implementation. See also [_4.5.1 Logical Operators and Short-circuit Control Forms_](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-5-1.html).

Comment: What happens if Day = 30 and Month = 2? (I would have a case statement on Month, which would make sure each month was covered just once, then test Day for being in range in each leg).

Comment: You can’t merge the two `if` statements as things stand, because the second one has the opposite sense to the first. You could try `if Day = 29 and Month = 2 and (Day mod 4 /= 0 or ... ) then raise Day_Error;` (the `...` is a bit complicated for me just at the moment, over to you)

Comment: You could write a function `bool IsDayLegalInMonth(date d)` or such (my Ada is rusty). Each month including February (with 29) has a maximum defined in a static array, so that  all 12 months can be handled uniformly. February alone needs a special second look, after the pathological cases have been excluded, considering the leap year case. By the way, I'd probably define a special type for the months, either an enumeration or, if there is too much computation involved, an Integer subtype.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot can be gained by putting certain tests in subroutines, even if they are only called once. In the code below I have a routine `GetMaxDayInMonth(Month, Year)` that gives the maximum day for the given month in the given year. The year is necessary only in the case of February, where the maximum allowed day of the month depends on whether it is in a leap year.

For all other months the return value is constant, which I have recorded in a const array `MaxDaysInMonth`. Only days in February must be treated specially. That treatment has again been stowed away in its own little subroutine `GetFebMaxDay(Day, Month)`, making everything neat and intelligible.

I have used the new Ada equivalent to the C ternary operator `cond?a:b`, `(if cond then a else b)`:

```
function GetFebMaxDay(Year: YearT) return DayInMonthT is
    begin
        return (if IsLeapYear(Year) then 29 else 28);
    end GetFebMaxDay;
```

The test for valid day then is thus reduced to a single function call

```
Date.Day <= GetMaxDayInMonth(Date.Month, Date.Year);
```

I have also created distinct types for year, month and day, imposing constraints where possible (max day in month is 31, after all). Many mistakes would have been avoided if programmers had put feet and meters in their own subtypes that need explicit conversion.

Here is the entire program that checks a few borderline dates:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure DateCheck is
    subtype     DayInMonthT is Integer range 1..31;
    type        MonthT is (JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC);
    subtype     YearT is Integer;
    type        DateT is record Year: YearT; Month: MonthT; Day: DayInMonthT; end record;
    
    function IsLeapYear(Y: YearT) return Boolean is
    begin
        return  (Y mod 4 = 0 and Y mod 100 /= 0) 
              or Y mod 400 = 0;
    end IsLeapYear;
    
    function GetFebMaxDay(Year: YearT) return DayInMonthT is
    begin
        return (if IsLeapYear(Year) then 29 else 28);
    end GetFebMaxDay;
    
    function GetMaxDayInMonth(Month: MonthT; Year: YearT) return DayInMonthT is 
        MaxDaysInMonth: constant array(MonthT) of DayInMonthT := 
                        (   JAN => 31,
                            FEB => 29,
                            MAR => 31,
                            APR => 30,
                            MAY => 31, 
                            JUN => 30,
                            JUL => 31, 
                            AUG => 31,
                            SEP => 30,
                            OCT => 31,
                            NOV => 30, 
                            DEC => 31 );
    begin return (if Month = FEB then GetFebMaxDay(Year) else MaxDaysInMonth(Month)); end;
    
    function IsValidateDate(Date: DateT) return Boolean is
    begin
        return Date.Day <= GetMaxDayInMonth(Date.Month, Date.Year);
    end;
    
    Dates: array (1..6) of DateT := (others => (0, JAN, 1));
    
begin
    Dates(1) := (2021, FEB, 28);
    Dates(2) := (2021, FEB, 29);
    Dates(3) := (2021, FEB, 30);
    Dates(4) := (2000, FEB, 31);
    -- Dates(4) := (2000, FEB, 32); -- raises warning, fails with constraint error
    Dates(5) := (2000, FEB, 29);
    Dates(6) := (1900, FEB, 29);
    for i in Dates'Range loop
        Put("Date ");
        Put(Dates(i).Year'Image);
        Put("-");
        Put(Dates(i).Month'Image);
        Put("-");
        Put(Dates(i).Day'Image);
        Put(": Valid date? ");
        Put_Line(IsValidateDate(Dates(i))'Image);
    end loop;
end DateCheck;
```

Sample session:

```
$ gnatmake -gnatwa datecheck.adb && ./datecheck.exe
gcc -c -gnatwa datecheck.adb
gnatbind -x datecheck.ali
gnatlink datecheck.ali
Date  2021-FEB- 28: Valid date? TRUE
Date  2021-FEB- 29: Valid date? FALSE
Date  2021-FEB- 30: Valid date? FALSE
Date  2000-FEB- 31: Valid date? FALSE
Date  2000-FEB- 29: Valid date? TRUE
Date  1900-FEB- 29: Valid date? FALSE
```